# Trying to select all objects where at least one associated object doesn't match the query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I have two associated models. A `Product` has many `DescriptorFiles`, and a `DescriptorFile` has a boolean attribute `approved`.

I want to find all products where none of the associated descriptor_files are approved.

That is to say: I want to find all products where ALL descriptor_files are `approved: false`.

I've just come up with a solution but I'd prefer to do it all with active record queries:

```
Product.all - Product.joins(:descriptor_files).where(descriptor_files: {approved: true})
```

This works, but as stated, it'd be great if I could return an active record object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails 5+ you can use `where.not` So in this case your query would be

```
Product.where.not(id: 
  Product.select(:id).joins(:descriptor_files)
      .where(descriptor_files: {approved: true})
)
```

This will use a sub query of your original version as a `NOT IN` clause.
Resulting SQL

```
SELECT 
  products.* 
FROM 
  products
WHERE 
  products.id NOT IN ( 
    SELECT 
      products.id
    FROM 
      products
      INNER JOIN descriptors ON descriptors.product_id = products.id
    WHERE 
      descriptors.approved = true
  )
```

Comment: I was aware of `where.not` but I never considered passing an array of id's that I wanted to exclude. This is very nice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can LEFT JOIN descriptor files that are approved and make sure you only retrieve records that has **joined nothing**. (This would also query Products with no descriptor files at all).

```
Product.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN descriptor_files ON descriptor_files.product_id = product.id AND descriptor_files.approved = true')
       .where(descriptor_files: { id: nil })
```

Unfortunately the join has to be written manually, though you could use Arel to generate a Join clause.

Comment: Wish I knew enough about SQL to understand how this works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `left_outer_joins` for rails 5 +

```
results = Product.left_outer_joins(:descriptor_files)
                      .where(descriptor_files: {approved: false})
```

Comment: This will find products where any descriptor file is false rather than where they are all false. Also left join with a where condition on the join table is an inner join